# Mac OS X Doesnt run .bashrc by itself

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app

When I open a new terminal I don't get the prompt I setup in ~/.bashrc or my aliases etc... If I run `exec $SHELL` then everything applies like it should for example:

```
Last login: Mon Jan  7 09:02:00 on console
osiris:~ adam$ exec $SHELL
[09:03:32][adam@osiris][~]
```

How do I get it to run everything on startup like it should?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mac OS X Terminal, in contrast to most other terminals, runs a login shell by default.

This means that `.bashrc` is not called. It will run `.bash_profile` instead, so you should source your `.bashrc` from there to have it executed.

See `man bash`, section "Invocation" for more info, as well as this blog article  by Josh Staiger:  [.bash_profile vs .bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)